# Fastest way to search MySQL Text for multiple terms: MySQL vs Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a database with 700 million rows (each with a `TEXT` field) and 500+ search terms. What is the fastest way to find all rows that contain at least one search term and insert them into a new table?

My first thought was to use the following

```
INSERT INTO my_new_table
    SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE text_field LIKE '%term1%' OR ... OR text_field LIKE '%term500%';
```

Or would Python be faster, with something like

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")
for row in cursor:
    if any(term in row[text_index] for term in search_terms):
        write_row_to_csv_or_mysql(row)
```

Or maybe there is a better way?

Comment: You could time the code to find out

Comment: First  comment are right ! And you asking "How to manage Data" , isn't python question.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  I realize this but how would you time the part where I ask "maybe there is a better way?". I posted the SQL query and Python code to show that I was attempting SOMETHING and not just blindly asking for a solution. Also, timing the two wouldn't give the option of a full text search as suggested in the first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the search in 700 million rows in my opinion it is bad to retrieve all data and search after (your python solution) and it is bad do make a query with like search (your sql solution)

a better solution based on mysql is to use full text search, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

an example here:

```
SELECT * FROM articles
    WHERE MATCH (title,body)
    AGAINST ('database' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

it is better again to use a dedicated dbms like elastic search,
https://www.elastic.co
a search dedicated database is generally faster and more scalable.